# Windows 10 DNS record with NT4 domain

Tags: windows-10, dns, samba, windows-domain, windows-nt-4

I'm having a problem introducing Windows 10 machines to my Samba NT4 domain.

I know that Microsoft actively "encourages" people to move to AD, but for various reasons, I'm stuck with NT4 for now.

After the registry fixes described in https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Required_Settings_for_Samba_NT4_Domains I'm able to join the computer to a domain "EXAMPLE".

Problem is, my domain uses a DNS suffix "example.net", and, while Windows 7 machines recognise that automatically and are resolvable via "computername.example.net", Windows 10 systems are not.

Here's an Nmap output for reverse DNS for my subnet for example:

```
Nmap scan report for user1.example.net (192.168.0.187)
....
Nmap scan report for USER2.EXAMPLE (192.168.0.191)
```

The result I'm looking for is for USER2.EXAMPLE to be resolvable as user2.example.net.

What should I look into to solve this?

Comment: But NT4 domains had nothing to do with DNS at all, so I don't understand how this causes join problems.

Comment: There is no "join" problems per se, the computer joins the domain successfully. I would think it's unrelated too, but combined with various workarounds to join a win10 machine to nt4 domain, I felt that it's useful to include this info. Also, the problem arises only on win10 computers, win7 work fine.

Comment: Well, the only possible relationship I see is that joining a machine sets the default search suffix for forward lookups, and that *might* influence how the system registers with a DNS server... What software runs your DNS domain (example.net), and what software runs the rDNS domain? It sounds like you're relying on the router to automatically provide rDNS, at least?

Comment: (I'm somewhat curious as to what reasons there are to still use NT4 domains with Windows 10...)